# A type of equilibrium points of a system of $2 \times 2$ equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, dynamical-systems

Consider the following system of equations $$x'(t)=ax(t)-cx(t)y(t)
$$ $$y'(t)=-by(t)+dx(t)y(t)$$

It has 2 equilibrium points $x_1=(0,0)$ and $x_2=(b/d,a/c)$.

Now we want to see that the function

$V(x,y)=d(x-b/d-(b/d)(Ln(dx/b)))+c(y-a/c-(a/c)Ln(cy/a))$ is Liapunov. So first I need to compute the equilibrium points. How do I do that? If I do this $V(x,y)=0,$ then how will I know the x and y values?

After this I will need to know for what values $a,b,c,d, V(x,y)>0$

But how should I proceed?

Can someone help me please?

Comment: @Moo yes,  do you something unusual?

Comment: @Moo yes, but that's how I found the equilibrium points, so it's the same? critical and equilibrium?

Comment: @Moo The lyapunov function  V(x) must be greater than zero in every point except in the equilibrium point  y and V(y)=0. Also $V'(x)\le 0$

Comment: And the conclusion would be that y is establish

Comment: @Moo mmh I don't think so. I can compute $V'(x)$ but then I don't know how to make it less or equal than 0.

Comment: Also a problem is that all the constants are positive, so I can put a minus sign on them.

Comment: why did you delete all  your comments? 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'equilibrium points' are the equilibrium points of the dynamical system, so the points where both $x' = 0$ and $y'=0$. As you found out, these are the origin $(0,0)$ and the point $(\frac{b}{d},\frac{a}{c})$.

For $V(x,y)$ to be a Lyapunov function, you must have that $V(x_*,y_*) = 0$ and $V(x,y) > 0$ everywhere else, where $(x_*,y_*)$ is the equilibrium of your choice. Now, if you try to compute $V(0,0)$, you run into problems, because $\text{ln} (0)$ doesn't exist: $\text{ln}(x) \to -\infty$ as $x \downarrow 0$. However, you can calculate that $V(\frac{b}{d},\frac{a}{c}) = 0$, so the equilibrium point $(\frac{b}{d},\frac{a}{c})$ is going to be our point of interest.

It's a bit more difficult to show that $V(x,y) >0$ everywhere else. What might help you is to replace $x$ and $y$ by $x \to \frac{b}{d} X$ and $y \to \frac{a}{c} Y$; then your function becomes
$$ b\left(X-1 - \text{ln}(X) \right) + a\left(Y-1 - \text{ln}(Y) \right) .$$
Now, you can try to show that the function
$$ f(z) = z - 1 - \text{ln}(z)$$
is positive everywhere, except for $z=1$, where $f(1) = 0$. For example, you can calculate the derivative $f'(z)$ and determine where $f'(z)$ is negative or positive, which tells you where $f(z)$ is decreasing or increasing. Once you have shown that $f(z)$ is positive everywhere (except at $z=1$), it is not difficult to conclude that $V(x,y)$ is positive everywhere, except at $(x,y) = (\frac{b}{d},\frac{a}{c})$.

Lastly, to show that this equilibrium $(x,y) = (\frac{b}{d},\frac{a}{c})$ is stable, you want that $\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d} t}\left[ V(x(t),y(t))\right] \leq 0$, where $(x(t),y(t))$ is a solution of the dynamical system. To calculate the above time derivative, we have to use the chain rule: $V$ is a function of both $x$ and $y$, and $x$ and $y$ themselves are a function of $t$. The derivative of the composite function $V(x(t),y(t))$ to time is therefore given by
$$ \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d} t}\left[V(x(t),y(t))\right] = \frac{\text{d} x}{\text{d} t} \, \frac{\partial V}{\partial x}(x(t),y(t))\,+\, \frac{\text{d} y}{\text{d} t} \, \frac{\partial V}{\partial y}(x(t),y(t)).$$
Now, you can use that $(x(t),y(t))$ are not just some unknown functions of $t$: no, $(x(t),y(t))$ are solutions of the dynamical system! Therefore, we can write $\frac{\text{d} x}{\text{d} t}$ in terms of $x(t)$ and $y(t)$, because we know that for solutions of the dynamical system, we have $\frac{\text{d} x}{\text{d} t} = x'(t) = a x(t) - c x(t) y(t)$. Of course, you can do the same for $\frac{\text{d} y}{\text{d} t}$. Once you work things out, you will see that, indeed, $\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d} t}\left[ V(x(t),y(t))\right] \leq 0$, so you can make your conclusions about the stability of the equilibrium $(x,y) = (\frac{b}{d},\frac{a}{c})$.

Comment: $f'(z)=1-(1/z)$ so it's positive everywhere except at 0, so $f(z)$ is increasing? and therefore $f(z)$ is positive everywhere except at $z=1$ and $z=0$? Am I correct?

Comment: Well, you're correct for $z>1$, where $f'(z)>0$. For $0<z<1$, this isn't true ($f'(z) < 0$ there), but that's actually useful. Try to draw the graph of $f(z)$ to see what I mean (check this [link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=z-1-ln(z),+0%3Cz%3C2) ).

Comment: I did, yes it's positive everywhere (except z=1) and now how come it's not difficult to conclude that $V(x,y)$ is positive everywhere except at $(x,y) = (\frac{b}{d},\frac{a}{c})$?

Comment: $V(x,y)$ is now this $b\left(X-1 - \text{ln}(X) \right) + a\left(Y-1 - \text{ln}(Y) \right) .$ So how do you know that will be positive except at $(x,y) = (\frac{b}{d},\frac{a}{c})?$

Comment: Try to find similarities between $V(x,y)$ and $f(z)$. Can you write the Lyapunov function in terms of $f(X)$ and $f(Y)$?

Comment: It would be $V(x,y)=bf(x)+af(y)$

Comment: from this one might say that $V(x,y)$ is positive except at $(1,1).$ But still how do you know $V(b/d,a/c)\le 0$?

Comment: Be careful here! You want the **time derivative** of $V(x(t),y(t))$ to be less than, or equal to, zero everywhere. The last paragraph of my answer addresses this. Also, don't forget that you changed variables from $(x,y)$ to $(X,Y)$, so actually, $V = b f(X) + a f(Y) = b f(\frac{d}{b} x) + a f(\frac{c}{a} y)$.

Comment: I see, and that's why $V({\frac{b}{d},\frac{a}{c}})=0$ so the point must be excluded from the domain where $V(x,y)>0.$

Comment: Where we use that $f$ is not positive at $1$?

Comment: The definition of a Lyapunov function, see e.g. [here (wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_function#Definition_of_a_Lyapunov_candidate_function), tells you that $V$ must be positive everywhere, *except* at the equilibrium point you're considering, where it must be zero.